# Ubuntu vs Fedora different keyboard behaviour

Tags: keyboard, tablet

I have a HP Spectre x360 Laptop (2015 version).

On fedora when I put the laptop in tablet mode the keyboard stays turned on.

On ubuntu when I put the laptop in tablet mode the keyboard turns off (same behaviour as Windows).

Is there anyway I can get Ubuntu to behave like Fedora, the reason is I would like to use the laptop as a keyboard (folded/'tablet mode') when connected to an external monitor. I am thinking there may be some GRUB settings or something?

Comment: Fedora 27 does not do this anymore(are you using 25 perhaps?) And I would assume this is a hardware issue: you probably need to disable the HID sensor. Your answer might be easier to get asking it on U&L: knowing how fedora does/did this might be a way to get it to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi what forum is 'U&L'?

Comment: I tried Fedora 25 and CentOS 7 which had the keyboard on behaviour.

Comment: This is the output of `lsmod` https://pastebin.com/8XeGc1YA

Comment: I tried blackisting these modules : https://pastebin.com/UnJ2eTGr But no luck